Removing a 1978 Tub/shower faucet cartridge
My home was built in 1978. The bezel is a kolher and the handle a moen so its unknown as to what this really is.
The dull plastic behind the shiny plastic exterior is free floating and just spins. The shiny piece, there is no screw, no inset piece holding it and it doesnt seem to screw off. I put quite a bit of pressure on it but Im a bit afraid to do more. How does this come off?


turn the ring ... if you remove the crud, then you'll see how it comes apart

clean the depositis first, then we can see

The single handle ball faucet is a common design, and it is fairly easy to find replacement parts, whatever the manufacturer.
Disassembly is simple, but may be difficult because the retaining (adjusting) ring may be hard to turn. The spanner wrenches, such as this Delta example at Amazon, have two pins to fit the slots in the ring. On occasion, I've bent those wrenches, and had to bend 'em back to shape. Often, the replacement ball, washer and O-ring kit comes with the wrench, as well. Repair kits are about US$10, such as these examples at Amazon.
Home Depot has an online illustrated guide to ball faucet repair.
As for the make and model of repair kit, only the valve matters, i.e., what is written on the bezel. However, the best way to get the correct kit is to remove the ball and associated parts and bring them to a hardware store to find a comparable kit.

I got a 2ft plastic pipe put on the end of the rubber wrench strap and just slowly kept pulling and it did finally break free. The threads were far better than one would think for being so stuck.
So neither Lowes or Locckes had the replacement parts that would fit. I just took everything to the store and the sizes were just well off. I replaced the two o-rings, used plumbers grease and greased the o-rings in the rear of the unit where the water comes out - cleaned the threads for the cap and got it all back together.
Thanks all for the help
